# Parsing HTML formatted attribute value to separate columns in database table

Tags: python, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I have an attribute field formatted using HTML all ready to go for Google Earth markers.

Here is the value:

```html
<div>
    Facility type: 
</div>
<div>
    Geoid: <a href="http://www.prisonersofthecensus.org/data/2010blocks/261450002001020/">261450002001020</a>
</div>
<div>
    County: Saginaw County
</div>
<div>
    2010 Correctional Population: 18
</div>
```

[image]

I tried to paste the actual HTML but couldn't figure out how to display it as text rather than formatted html!

I've love to have separate attribute fields for the columns within that string:

Facility Type
County
2010 Correctional Population

Can this be done using Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming python and you want as a result a dict

```py
{ "Facility Type" : None, 
  "Geoid": "<a ...",
  "County" : "Saginaw County",
  "2010 Correctional Population": 18
}
```

you could use

```py
mystr = "<div>Facility type: </div><div>Geoid: <blah></div><div>County: Saginaw County</div><div>Pop: 18</div>"
parts = mystr.replace("<div>","").split("</div>")
r = {}
for part in parts:
    kv = part.split(":")

    if kv[0].strip() != "":
        r[kv[0]] = kv[1].strip()
```

Result is `{'Facility type': '', 'County': 'Saginaw County', 'Geoid': '<blah>', 'Pop': '18'}`

This does not handle the type conversion of the appropriate attributes, but that can be done.